# Python keyboard not working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pdf, keyboard

I would like automate the process of opening a pdf in Chrome and using the print to pdf function to download a flattened copy of the file for data extraction purposes. When I run this code, the first file works just fine, but the second and third files fail to open the print window after opening in chrome. I suspect the problem has something to do with the keyboard entries but I am unfamiliar with the library.

```
import os
from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard, time
files = ["file:///C:/Users/akcgo/Documents/CARB/ARBER/PDFS/Company B save.pdf",
         "file:///C:/Users/akcgo/Documents/CARB/ARBER/PDFS/SOC 8 essay.pdf"
         "file:///C:/Users/akcgo/Documents/CARB/ARBER/PDFS/Company A save.pdf"]
counter = 1
for file in files:
    name = "test" + str(counter)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(file)
    keyboard.press(['ctrl', 'p'])
    keyboard.release(['ctrl', 'p'])
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press('enter')
    keyboard.release('enter')
    # initiates the print process
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.write(name)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press('enter')
    keyboard.release('enter')
    # saves the document
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.quit()
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the keyboard package.
But you can import Keys from Selenium itself.

`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

You can then use this to press keys. Something like -

`your_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`